# Iphone salesforce 1 screen scroll up on clicking of link or accordation?

Tags: salesforce1-app, bootstrap

Developed a user interface in salesforce 1 using bootstrap accordion when i expanded a tab at bottom screen scrolled upward. How can i stop this behavior.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are using a `<div>` - that's a known issue with Bootstrap. Switch to using a `<span>` and it should stop that scrolling behaviour.  More details available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489625/bootstrap-accordion-scrolling-behaviour-on-collapse).

You can also control the scrolling behavior explicitly using  `$.scrollTo()`